# Font in Word 2010 table changes from default font

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am running Office 2010 on Windows 7.  Default font is Arial 10pt.  Until recently I have not had issues, but over the past few weeks when I create tables the font is Times New Roman 10pt.  I have checked the Table Text style, which is Arial 10pt, and the Normal style which is Arial 10pt.
Where else can I check?

Comment: Check the style setting of the table, under table tools design, some of the "pretty" ones have default fonts.

Comment: All tables have a default font. If you select the table and, as Steve says, go to Design under Table Tools, the table design used by your table will be highlighted. Right click on the highlighted table design, select Modify Table Style. You can change the default font and font size in the dialog box that opens.

Comment: @burrowsrjl This didn't work for me - I changed to a `Calibri` table cell, but when I insert a new table row, it keeps going back to `Arial`. Very frustrating. Update: I had a hyperlink in a table cell that gave me a right-click "Font" context menu item that I then used to change and set as the default font. Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

this is a few years late, but I was struggling with the same thing.  I had to clear the font style from the Quick Styles menu in order the for the font in the table style to show up.  Select the entire table and then select "Clear Formatting" under the Quick Styles drop menu (arrow with the bar above).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Folks
Seems that I also managed to get this done. See below the steps:

1. Select the entire table clicking on the  top left part
2. Go to the "Home" tab
3. On the "Style" menu click on the expand button (located at the bottom right - little arrow and box)
4. Clear all styles
5. While selecting the table go back to "style" menu
6. Expand the style menu and on the bottom click "apply Style"
7. Automatically MS Word will create a new style named "table Grid"
8. From there you define the specific font and preferences for the new tables generated.

Note this style can be applied for 1 document or become a new template for other documents

cheers hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Revised for 2022, Microsoft 365 V2108 ... menus have changed
The table style overwrites the font in the table. New text pasted into the table is a different font or font size.

1. Select the table
2. In the Ribbon, Table Design tab, Table Styles select the More down arrow (right, bottom of table styles)
3. Select Modify Table Style (bottom left)
4. Set the font and font size in the Modify Style dialog
5. Select OK